# Trying to read products from back4app onto a web page with carditem view React & Back4APP

Tags: reactjs, back4app

I am currently trying to produce a forum page where users can post products onto a forum page for other users to see. I have it writing to the db and saving the products - however i now want to read back from the products and produce each product for other users to see. Cant seem to find much guidance on it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg5X5.png)
Image is current code of the readProducts function that I have created. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (async () => {
  // Creates a new Query object to help us fetch MyCustomClass objects
 const query = new Parse.Query('MyCustomClass');
 try {
  // Executes the query, which returns an array of MyCustomClass
  const results = await query.find();
  console.log(`ParseObjects found: ${JSON.stringify(results)}`);
 } catch (error) {
   console.log(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
 }
 })();
```

Comment: this code from https://dashboard.back4app.com/apidocs#queries

Comment: https://www.back4app.com/docs/react/data-objects/react-data-types - I have followed this guide for creating the products. Should i follow a similar layout for reading back from the database? just looking to return a list of the products onto a web page.

Comment: res.json(results)